# Unable to find Attribute option?

Tags: custom-attributes, dynamic

Hi I can't find the Attribute option in blender working on something with Dynamic Paint.
Refer the screenshot[image]

Comment: Screenshot of the brush can't aid, share canvas settings.

Comment: I think he means that there is no button in the dialog which is usually there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You mean the *Viewport Shading > Color > Vertex* option, right? This got renamed in Blender 3.2. Have a look at the manual. [3.1 *Viewport Shading > Color > Vertex*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/render/workbench/color.html?highlight=Vertex) and [3.2 *Viewport Shading > Color > Attribute*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.2/render/workbench/color.html?highlight=Attribute), referenced by [Viewport Shading > Solid > Color](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html?highlight=Color#solid)